# Why my one hot encoded labels and my label don't match each other?

Tags: numpy, keras, scikit-learn, numpy-ndarray, one-hot-encoding

I was working on a multi class classification model, 15 classes, using to_categorical to one hot encode my label. When I test to see if my one hot encoded labels and my label in int match, they don't match.
Here is the code:

```
X = df.copy()
Y = X.pop('label')

xTrain, xTest, yTrain, yTest = train_test_split(X,Y, test_size=0.2)
xTrain = xTrain.to_numpy()
columnsToScale = ['PriceReg', 'ItemCount', 'demand1', 'demand2', 'demand3']
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
xTrain = scaler.fit_transform(xTrain)
xTest = scaler.transform(xTest)
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
one_hot_yTrain = to_categorical(yTrain, num_classes=15)
one_hot_yTest = to_categorical(yTest,num_classes=15)
```

When I check for example:

```
one_hot_yTrain[11]
```

I got:

```
array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
      dtype=float32)
```

meanwhile for:

```
yTrain[11]
```

I got:

```
3
```

I expected that yTrain[11] to be 11
Did I misunderstand something? Appreciate any explanations

Comment: It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  In particular, it looks like an minimal example could be as simple as `yTrain = <something>; one_hot_yTrain = to_categorical(yTrain, num_classes=15)` (plus whatever imports are needed to make that reproducible).

Comment: My original labels were just int numbers from 0 to 14. Each number for each class. The code in my question is most of the code I had so far. I just don't understand why after separating my dataframe, and covert features into numpy array then one_hot_encode labels. my one hot encode labels don't know match the original int labels